# Prove that $M\oplus N$ is closed subspace in banach space $X$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

let $M$ and $N$ be closed linear subspace of a Banach space $X$ such that $M \ \cap N=\{0\}.$

prove that $M\oplus N$ is closed in $X$ if and only if there is a constant $K>0\ $ such that $||x-y||\geq K \ \forall \ x\in M,y \ \in N$  with $||x||=||y||=1.$

any suggestion  how to approach

Comment: In which book, we can find your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sufficiency is quite straightforward to prove. First of all note that the inequality gives you that for any $x \in M$ and $y \in N\setminus \{0\}$ we have 
$\|x\| K \leq \|x+ \frac{\|x\|}{\|y\|} y \|$. But by the triangle inequality and the reverse triangle inequality, we have
$$
\|x+ \frac{\|x\|}{\|y\|} y \| \leq \|x+y\|+ \| y - \frac{\|x\|}{\|y\|} y \|  \leq 2 \| x+y \|.
$$

Take a sequence $(z_n)_n$ in $M \oplus N$ that converges to some $z \in X$. Then write it as $z_n = x_n +y_n$ with $x_n \in M$ and $y_n \in N$. Then it's easy to prove that $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence by using the above property.

The converse is proven by looking at the map
$$
T: M\oplus N \to M: (x,y) \mapsto x.
$$
Because both $M\oplus N$ and $M$ are closed, they must be Banach spaces. The closed graph theorem will provide that $T$ is continuous. So there is a constant $A>0$ such that $\|x\| =\|T(x,y)\| \leq A\|x+y \|$.

Comment: why is $||x ||K \leq \ || x+y||$, with $|| y||=1$?

Comment: @Eklavya I edited my answer, what I wrote before probably wasn't entirely correct.

Comment: from where 2 come from in expression $2|| x+y||$??

Comment: It comes from the reverse triangle inequality:
$\| y - \frac{\|x\|}{\|y\|} y \| = \lvert \|y \| - \|x\| \rvert \leq  \| x+y\|$.

Comment: By closed graph theorem, we only have $\lVert T(x,y)\rVert\leq A(\lVert x\rVert+\lVert y\rVert).$ What's the reason for the last line?

Comment: You view $M \oplus N$ as a subspace of $X$, so the norm on $\| (x,y) \|$ is simply equal $\|x+y\|$. If you regard $M \oplus N$ as it's own space with norm $\|x\| + \|y\|$, it will always be a Banach space if $M$ and $N$ are Banach spaces so the whole thing would become trivial.

Comment: @Demophilus Is $M \oplus N$ always closed subspace? because $M,N$ both subspace, easy to see $M \oplus N$ is still subspace. $\forall \{z_n\} \subseteq M \oplus N$ convergent, there exist $\{x_n\} \subseteq M, \{y_n\} \subseteq N$ such that $z_n = x_n+y_n$. because $M,N$ both closed, so $\exists x \in M, x_n \to x$ and $\exists y \in N, y_n \to y$, let $z = x+y \in M \oplus N$, then $\|z_n-z\| = \|(x_n+y_n)-(x+y)\| \le \|x_n-x\|+\|y_n-y\| \to 0 (n \to \infty)$, so $z_n \to z \in M \oplus N$, that means $M \oplus N$ is closed. Is that right?

Comment: @xunitc No, M $\oplus$ N is not always closed. There are counterexamples. Your proof does not work because there's no guarantee that $x_n$ and $y_n$ converge.

Comment: @Demophilus Thank you, I know my mistake.